# How can i enable bootstrap tooltip in highchart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

How can I  enable bootstrap tooltip in highchart when mouse hover.Below is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/74ngk01q/16/) some one   could you please help me on that.  I created the text says "Here Need to show tool tip" . When i mouse hover on that text need to show the tooltip/popover.

```
$("#t123").tooltip({placement: 'left', title:"HELLO TITLE!"});
```

Answer (score 0):

In highcharts you can catch [mouseOver](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.point.events.mouseOver) / mouseOut events and then call your custom action.

Docs for events:
- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts
- [customEvents](http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/15/Custom-Events) plugin which allows to add extra events.